# No cargar css con wp_enqueue_style en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-plugin

Estoy intentando crear un plugin que enlace a un css de "bxSlider" siguiendo un tutorial pero en este punto me falla:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: BXSlider para WordPress
Plugin URI: http://easy-webdev.com
Description: Añade BxSlider a WooCommerce
Version: 1.0
Author: xxxx
Author URI:
Text Domain:
Domain Path:
*/

//No permitir que se cargue directamente
defined('ABSPATH') or die ('No Script kiddies please!');

//Obtener un Path
define( 'WCSLIDER_PATH',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

//Cargar Stylesheets
function wcslider_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style('bxslider', WCSLIDER_PATH. '/css/jquery.bxslider.min.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wcslider_scripts');

?>
```

Se supone que se deberia cargar el "jquery.bxslider.min.css" a Wordpress pero al hacer una busqueda (actualizando la pagina) no aparece por ninguna parte. 
¿Alguien podria decirme por que no se carga?

Comment: fijate en la pestaña network (red) del devtools (herramientas de desarrollador) si la url desde la cual intenta cargar el css es la correcta

Comment: Puede que tengas un problema con la URL que se construye combinando: `WCSLIDER_PATH. '/css/jquery.bxslider.min.css'` , creo que deberías imprimirla y verificar que el archivo está ahí vía navegador. Otra cosa que deberías hacer es limpiar el caché del navegador.

Comment: Si, creo que es lo más probable, que no exista la css por que lo la encuentro al hacer una busqueda. No se como verificar via navegador. No creo que tome WCSLIDER_PATH como ruta valida. ¿Como puedo hacer?

Comment: Lo extraño es que al parecer tú quieres poner el `css` en el mismo directorio del plugin. Por lo general las hojas de estilo se guardan todas en el mismo directorio y para enlazarlas tú usas luego `get_template_directory_uri() `, que te trae la url donde se encuentran los archivos `.css`.  [Mira los ejemplos de código mostrados en esta página](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/), quizá te ayuden a organizar mejor el contenido.

Comment: Como decia, estoy siguiendo un curso, y en él, el sistema  utilizado es este. Me gustaria saber como puedo hacer un echo o var_dump()  de 
wp_enqueue_style('bxslider', WCSLIDER_PATH. '/css/jquery.bxslider.min.css');
para ver que  esta cargado realmente

Comment: Por cierto, la hoja de estilo del plugin esta dentro de la carpeta css de este mismo plugin como indicas. El  contenido pues esta organizado correctamente.

Comment: La cuestión no es saber lo que devuelve `wp_enqueue_style` sino verificar a qué URL estás apuntando exactamente. Lo que deberías hacer es un `var_dump(plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));`, pues eso es lo que tú le estás asignando a la constante `WCSLIDER_PATH` que debería contener la URL del archivo css que quieres enlazar.  Y con un `echo WCSLIDER_PATH. '/css/jquery.bxslider.min.css'` te debería imprimir la URL **exacta** en la que se está tratando de buscar el archivo `css`. Puede que el problema sea cuestión de un `/` de más o de menos.

Comment: Estoy probando esto pero no muestra nada
function wcslider_scripts(){
 wp_enqueue_style('bxslider', WCSLIDER_PATH. '/css/jquery.bxslider.min.css');
 echo WCSLIDER_PATH . '/css/jquery.bxslider.min.css';
 var_dump(plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wcslider_scripts');

¿Lo tengo mal escrito o deberia ponerlo en otro lugar?

Comment: ¿Probaste a hacer un `var_dump(plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));`  y un `echo WCSLIDER_PATH. '/css/jquery.bxslider.min.css';`  para luego revisar cómo se está construyendo la ruta y si el archivo está ahí efectivamente?  El resultado del `echo` tú puedes copiarlo y pegarlo en el navegador y si no te abre el css que esperas significa que debes corregir la ruta.

Comment: El resultado de var_dump(plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)); es esto:
string(164) "http://localhost/CursoWordpress/tiendaVirtual/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/C:/xampp/htdocs/CursoWordpress/tiendaVirtual/wordpress/wp-content/themes/miTiendaVirtual/"

El resultado de echo WCSLIDER_PATH es lo mismo es decir: WCSLIDER_PATH

Pienso que no es correcto porque desde esa url no se construye la ruta al css. No se como arreglarlo. He quitado la primera barra como aconsejabas pero no  funciona.

Comment: Prueba a ponerlo así: **`define(  'WCSLIDER_PATH',  dirname( __FILE__ ) );`**

Comment: Acabo de ver porque no funcionaba: No tenia activado el plugin. (estoy golpeandome aun la cabeza) Un millon de gracias.